# dynamic windowing based on the timestamp

Tags: duplicates, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to remove the duplicates based on the event when it was first seen.
It is very crucial for me, not to use TumblingEventWindow because the window time is fixed. What I currently have is this exact logic [remove duplicates using ttl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883008/flink-deduplication-and-processwindowfunction). But with this approach, if there is some issue and if we want to catch up on old data, then this ttl based duplicates removal is not helping (giving less than expected numbers as more events starts to fit within this ttl window due to the catchup process).

is there any way to remove duplicates based on the event time and also when catching up the lag when needed?

Update 1:
I tried using KeyedProcessFunction to remove duplicates based on event time, but i dont see the onTimer function is getting called. Could not figure what is off here.

```
public class DeduplicateKeyedProcessFunc extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Event, Event> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeduplicateKeyedProcessFunc.class);
    private transient ValueState<SearchImaGuidInterimMessageVO> lastTimestampState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);

        // Initialize state for the last event timestamp
        ValueStateDescriptor<Event> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("exist", Event.class);
        lastTimestampState = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Event event, Context context, Collector<Event> collector) throws Exception {
        long eventTimeStamp = event.getEventTimeStamp();
        if(lastTimestampState.value() == null) {
            logger.info("Record for key does not exist: " + eventTimeStamp);
            lastTimestampState.update(event);
            context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(eventTimeStamp + (5 * 60 * 1000));
        } else {
            logger.info("Record for key exists: " + eventTimeStamp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<Event> collector) throws Exception {
        logger.info("record removed: " + timestamp);
        // This method is invoked when the event-time timer registered in `processElement()` fires
        Event currentRecord = lastTimestampState.value();
        if(currentRecord != null) {
            collector.collect(currentRecord);
        }
        lastTimestampState.update(null);
    }
}
```

Update 2:
I assigned the watermark strategy before calling the above function through

> .assignWatermarkStrategy().keyBy().process(new
> DeduplicateKeyedProcessFunc())

and the timer started to get triggered.

Comment: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/deduplication/ and https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-deduplication/

Comment: @DavidAnderson the references are SQL. I am looking for java streaming APIs. any such references would be helpful

Comment: That's easily done with a KeyedProcessFunction and timers.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried the same using KeyedProcessFunction but i dont see my onTimer function is getting called. do you have any suggestions here (updated the post)?

Comment: Instead of `lastTimestampState.update(null);` you should use `lastTimestampState.clear();`. Glad you figured out the need for watermarks.

Comment: eventtimestamp may be old and  eventTimeStamp + (5 * 60 * 1000) may point a past time.           `long currentTime = ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime();`
            `long windowSizeMillis = (long) 5 * 60 * 1000;`
`long nextTriggerTime = currentTime + windowSizeMillis;`
            `ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(nextTriggerTime);`